# How to remove background color from the image without affecting the text using opencv python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I tried to remove the black color from the image, if i tried the text also removed.

[image: Original Image]

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('test.png')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv)
thresh1 = cv2.threshold(s, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
thresh2 = cv2.threshold(v, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
thresh2 = 255 - thresh2
mask = cv2.add(thresh1, thresh2)
result = img.copy()
result[mask == 128] = (255, 255, 255)
cv2.imwrite('clear.png', result)
```

Please give some ideas to get the text from that image.

Comment: Getting the text, automatically? Like using `pytesseract`? I'd say that's impossible for the given image. Some of the letters themselves (like the M in DOMENTATION) can't be recognized properly. Also, the colors of the text and the background are too similar. The overall image quality is bad, the image size is low. So, I don't think, you'll get a reasonable result.

Comment: can you add the output image too ? I would like to compare and use your script on other images